# check if file in a restricted folder exist in php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I'm using a head request as follows in order to check if a given file exist or not.

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{
    //file not exists
},
success: function()
{
    //file exists
}
});
```

However, now I'm putting the files in a folder which is restricted by .htaccess through the following rule

```
deny from all
```

But now it looks like jquery is always returning 404 Not Found as a result of trying to access a resricted folder.

I can't give up on restricting this folder as the files are being uploaded by users and I can't be sure they are safe.

How can I check if a file exist in this folder ? given that this file exist on the same domain ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `file_exists()` function inside the `.php` file itself, instead of using it directly in your Ajax code? The server probably thinks that the call from inside a JS/Ajax isn't a valid serverside call, but a client-side call.

Comment: Actually, I need to keep cheking for the file until it is uploaded so I have to use ajax . But your answer gave me a clue. I think I could make a new file which checks for the needed file through file_exist then call this file through ajax.   Will give it a try. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php to look for the file, and handle it via jQuery...

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "somephpfile.php?file=filename.txt",
    success: function(file_exists) {
        if(file_exists) {
            alert("File Exists");
        }
    }
});
```

**php**

```
<?php
if(file_exists($_GET["file"])) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Make sure you have some security in the php logic to make sure it can't be used to hack your server!

Answer (score 0):

you cant access the files behind .htaccess unless the user is already logged in and has access to the files. You can make a public page (php) that takes a file name as a parameter, and then do server side checks to see if the file exists, and return a JSON object or true/false.. something like this:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://www.example.com/checkfile.php?locn=somefile.ext',
error: function()
{
    //this happens when jquery cant contact your php script or your server threw an error... 404's and 500's... just show a generic "cant connect to server" or something.
},
success: function(data)
{
    //this means you got data back from the server as a 200 response. 
    //it does not say whether or not the file exists. 
    //to do that, you must examine the JSON response. perhaps like this:
    if (data == true)
    {
        //the file exists
    }
    else
    {
        //the file does not exist
    }
}
});
```

your checkfile.php might look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
$fileloc = $_GET["locn"];
if (file_exists($locn))
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```